# Assigning individual items of foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, asp.net-web-api

i'm a newbie, I wanted to assign items from the foreach loop as a radio button text. I was wondering is there a better way to do than to assign the items to a list and calling it. Can i make use repeaters here?

back-end code:

```
foreach(XmlNode fruits in basket)
    {
        var fruitname = fruits.SelectSingleNode("fruit");
    }
```

aspx code:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" Groupname="optionsRadios2" runat="server" value="option1"/><br />
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" Groupname="optionsRadios2" runat="server" value="option2"/><br />
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" Groupname="optionsRadios2" runat="server" value="option3"/><br />
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207315/asp-net-creating-dynamic-radio-button-list - This should get you on the right track.

Comment: You can use radio button list: see this if u have xml datasource http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636059/radiobuttonlist-inside-repeater-bound-to-xmldatasource